# Mongo C# strongly typed index on nested array property

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

Using MongoDB C# Driver 2.3, what's the strongly typed version of the following code?

```
database.GetCollection<GamePlay>()
    .Indexes
    .CreateOne("{ \"PartiesInGame.Username\": 1 }");
```

`GamePlay` has an `IEnumerable<PartyInGame>`, where `PartyInGame` has a `public string Username { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads up but for now Robert Stam has said you cannot do this at present but they are planning it for a future release you can track it here... [CSHARP-1955](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1955)